# Add file path of attachment to body of email

Tags: vba, outlook, email-attachments

My work inbox has a very small size limit.

**What I want to do:** Every time a user attaches a file to an email, the path to the location that the user pulls the file from will be automatically added to the bottom of the body of the email and linked. That way, attachments can be deleted from the email (saving space), but the link to the file will remain intact, so when you're looking through emails you can still find the related attachment.

If more than one file is added, more than one link will be added. If files are added then deleted, the links will follow suit.

This macro would be distributed to everyone I work with and it would constantly be running so every email would have links to every attachment.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at [this code](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=953) as a slightly better alternative. In your scenario, it would need to be expected that the attachment was not on the users local PC when they uploaded. In the link I provided, it will save the attachment to a defined location, removes the attachment from the email, and then edits the email with where the file was saved.

Comment: I'll take a look at this when I get into the office tomorrow. You're correct in saying it would need to be expected that the attachment was not on the user's local PC. That is a valid expectation working in my office environment, everyone works on the same network drive. I'll dig into the code tomorrow and see if it helps. Thanks a lot, didn't think anyone was going to reply.